# A Linux Distribution w/ Version which contains Sendmail version 8.6.9

Tags: security, unix, root, c, sendmail

I'm looking for Sendmail version 8.6.9. What distribution (I don't think that matters) or version of said distribution contains the old 8.6.9 version of sendmail. If I'm going about getting that sendmail version wrong, please advise me on how I would go about it.

If your wondering why, I'm looking to play around with the Sendmail 8.6.9 IDENT Remote Root Vulnerability from 1994.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find a live distribution (that was from 1994), but can download the source used in Slackware 2.1 and compile and configure it (see [link](http://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware-2.1/source/n/sendmail/)).